# Android studio NDK Undefined reference to GL functions

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I made small JNI-based project.
I do #include GLES3/gl3.h in my C code and it works. But when I try to use ANY OpenGL function it says Undefined reference to gl*. My Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -Wextra
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv3 -ldl -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What I am doing wrong? Could some one tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `-lGLESv2`?

Comment: It's definitely a problem with the way you link `-lGLESv3` and it would also be worth noting that there are some emulators that simply **will not** run GLESv3 (although this should not affect your linking)

Comment: I am running it on real device ( Samsung tab 3 ), and I tried to include -lGLESv2, still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try linking to [EGL](https://www.khronos.org/egl) as well.

For my projects, I use these libraries:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv3
```